# Why isn't Google crawling on my blog?

Tags: googlebot, web-crawlers, google-index

I have [a blog](http://www.mycsnippets.blogspot.com). I made it in August, 2010. It has been awhile, but I am unable to make Google crawl on my site. I have requested Google to crawl but there is still no response. Are there any reasons of note why it is happening?

Comment: I've just now found Google's cache of your page on 16 Nov 2011. Don't say this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see it's a blogspot blog so I'll skip most of the common reasons that googlebot might not visit.

Did you get any inbound links? Put your blog on some free directories and social networks and see what will happen.

Comment: I have 13 backlinks so far,still no crawling

Comment: Try adding some more. I looked through it and failed to see any other reasons.

Comment: don't see how this answers the question. Using backlinks can make the indexing / crawling faster but to be honest theres most more constructive things you can be doing with social media and building even more content the time it takes to worry about crawling times.

Answer (score 1):

You don't to request that Googlebot visits your blog.  You don't need to worry.
First of all, you just write as many articles as you can (but with good quality.)
Advertise them among your friends then on social networking sites.
Once your site start getting traffic, you'll automatically be included in search results.

Moreover, register your site with Google Analytics and Google Webmaster Tools. Those will show statistics about the actual activity of the Googlebot crawler.

Comment: I tried pinging google with my blog name and it worked

Answer (score 1):

If you want fast and guaranteed crawling, create a google adsense account and ad the google ad to the source code of your site.  You can do this just until they spider the site, and you can probably do it on pages that simply link to your important content, and which only spiders are otherwise going to be likely to find.  Since they advertise based on content, they'll have to spider your site, discover it's existence, index it, and presumably index all of the pages that you actually -want- it to see as well.

Then remove the ads whenever you're ready.

Comment: How does adding advertisement help?Some days back I tried putting google adds on my site but they replied back that the site was not of good quality : /

Comment: AdSense spider and Search spider are different.