# What is the best way to get robots to crawl your site from google?

Tags: google, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isnt google crawling on my blog?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6351/why-isnt-google-crawling-on-my-blog)

What is the best way to get robots to crawl your site from google?

With reference to our site

[site elided]

Comment: Adding the link to a stackoverflow question is a good start.... removed.

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to register for Google's [webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) to submit an [XML site map](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184).

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML sitemap and Html sitemap both to get crawl by google submitting [Sitemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_map).

The other step is [Html Sitemap](http://www.ehow.com/sitemap-1112170.html).

You can use [Google Webmaster Tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) to submit XML Sitemap.